# ¿Como hacer una consulta sql server con pivot?

Tags: sql-server

tengo una tabla con esta estructura.
[*rs_indice_ejemplo*]
[[image: rs_indice_ejemplo]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/il9xk.png)

Necesito que la consulta devuelva el resultado como esa imagene. La suma total será hecha por VBA acceder a la base de datos SQL Server.
[image: rs_indice_sumar]

La consulta que estoy intentando hacer es esa.

```
 select *
  from (
        select 
        irec.cod_emp,irec.ano_mes,fx.nome_faixa,irec.saldo_inicial,irec.entradas,
        irec.devolucion,irec.monto_pagado,irec.porcent_baja,irec.porcent_pagado
        from rs_indices_ejemplo irec
        inner join rs_faixa_atraso fx(nolock) on irec.cod_faixa = fx.cod_faixa
 )s
 pivot (
    max(saldo_inicial)
    for[nome_faixa] in ([DE 0 a 30],[DE 31 a 60],[DE 61 a 90],[DE 91 a 120] )
 )p
```

Y me devuelve eso: (yo sé que hace falta un case when para cambiar los meses)
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Gracias por cualquier ayuda.
Bonfim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El detalle es que no puedes hacer sólo un `PIVOT`, también necesitarías usar `UNPIVOT`. Otro punto es que no me gustan esos operadores porque son muy limitados en funcionalidad y no aportan una mejora en rendimiento. En su lugar, uso agregado condicional en vez de Pivot y constructores de tabla de valores para Unpivot. De esa forma, controlo mejor como quedan los resultados.

```
SELECT  irec.cod_emp,
        irec.ano_mes,
        up.concepto,
        MAX( CASE WHEN fx.nome_faixa = 'DE 0 a 30'   THEN Valor END) AS [DE 0 a 30],
        MAX( CASE WHEN fx.nome_faixa = 'DE 31 a 60'  THEN Valor END) AS [DE 31 a 60],
        MAX( CASE WHEN fx.nome_faixa = 'DE 61 a 90'  THEN Valor END) AS [DE 61 a 90],
        MAX( CASE WHEN fx.nome_faixa = 'DE 91 a 120' THEN Valor END) AS [DE 91 a 120]
FROM        rs_indices_ejemplo irec
INNER JOIN  rs_faixa_atraso    fx  ON irec.cod_faixa = fx.cod_faixa
CROSS APPLY ( VALUES( 1, 'Saldo inicial'       , irec.saldo_inicial),
                    ( 2, 'Entradas'            , irec.entradas),
                    ( 3, 'Devolución con pagos', irec.devolucion),
                    ( 4, 'Monto pagado'        , irec.monto_pagado),
                    ( 5, 'Porcent de bajas'    , irec.porcent_baja),
                    ( 6, 'Porcent de pagos'    , irec.porcent_pagado)) up( Orden, Concepto, Valor)
GROUP BY irec.cod_emp,
        irec.ano_mes,
        up.Orden,
        up.concepto
ORDER BY irec.cod_emp,
        irec.ano_mes,
        up.Orden;
```

Comment: Luis Cazares, gracias por tu respuesta. 
Ao ejecutar la consulta me sale el mensage:Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 18 Incorrect syntax near 'up'.
El mensaje refierese a esa linea:( ( 6, 'Porcent de pagos'    , irec.porcent_pagado)up( Orden, Concepto, Valor)).

Comment: Me faltó un paréntesis, pero ya está corregido.

Comment: Luis, muchas gracias. La consulta resultó lo que deseaba. Saludos desde Brasil.